# How can I wait a second between two printf in c?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 10/13 with c, and I want to wait a few seconds between two `printf` statements:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int a,b;
do
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
    //wait 1 sec
    system("cls");
    printf("%d\n", b);
}while(1)
```

When it's ready, it should generate the framerate of a little game.
For example, waiting 0.5 sec gives about 2 frames per sec.

Comment: I guess using time() to wait for one second is just too extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use

```
    Sleep(1000);
```

Header-windows.h

Comment: thanks it work with #include <windows.h>

Comment: General rule accpet answer , anyway go up with your code :)